# How to sort a hashmap consisting of Class objects as key and another hashmap as value in java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm fairly new to Java and found some resources on how to sort the hashmap based on certain attributes of the key object. However, I'm still not able to figure out what I'm missing in my code.

I would really appreciate any help.

I have a Monkey class, one of whose attribute is name. And, the location of the monkey could be either {"isolationId" : someInteger} or {"enclosureId": someInteger}.

And my hashmap looks like this:

```
HashMap<Monkey, HashMap<String, Integer>> monkeyAndLocation = new HashMap<Monkey, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
```

Now, I want to sort the `monkeyAndLocation` with respect to the name attribute of the monkey object.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: I can't imagine what you've been reading, but sorting a hashmap is a contradiction in terms. Are you looking for a `TreeMap`?

Comment: For now, I dont really care about performance, so as long as something works, its good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: You cannot sort a `HashMap`. Technically you can't sort *any* Map type, but some map types can control the iteration order of their entries to emulate being sorted.

A `TreeMap` maintains order of its entries, so load one with the contents of your map, providing the `Comparator` it should use to order its entries.

First change the definition of your map to its abstract type - see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

```
Map<Monkey, Map<String, Integer>> monkeyAndLocation = new HashMap<>();
```

To convert this map to one that is "sorted" (iterates in sort order):

```
Map<Monkey, Map<String, Integer>> monkeyAndLocationSorted 
  = new TreeMap<>(Comparators.comparing(Monkey::getName));
monkeyAndLocationSorted.putAll(monkeyAndLocation);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want a sorted copy of your Map, you could just do (apparently your map should be filled with something):

```
private Map<Monkey, HashMap<String, Integer>> sortMonkeys(){
        Map<Monkey, HashMap<String, Integer>> monkeyAndLocation = new HashMap<Monkey, HashMap<String, Integer>>();
        return new TreeMap<>(monkeyAndLocation);
    }
// the Monkey class should reside in a file of its own!
private static class Monkey implements Comparable<Monkey>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Monkey other){
        return name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
    String name;
    Integer isolationId;
    Integer enclosureId;
}
```

The TreeMap sorts by the natural order of its keys. So by implementing Comparable you set the natural order to the order of the names of the monkeys.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but you have used  a ```Map``` instead of the```HashMap``` that I was using before. Does that make any difference?

Comment: @sparklyCode You could declare your Map a a HashMap or a Map and than assign an instance of a HashMap to it. The advantage of declaring it as a Map is, you can easily change the underlying implementation (i.e. to a TreeMap) without changing anything else. So, if you plan to use the map as a return value of a method, you are more flexible by declaring it as the appropriate interface. If you want to make sure, the method returns a sorted map, you would not define the return value as Map but rather as a SortedMap but would avoid a definition as TreeMap. So the user doesn't need the impl. details